# Can I use Lodash to "collapse" an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Currently my array looks something like

```
[{index: 1, value: 'A'},
 {index: 1, value: 'B'},
 {index: 2, value: 'C'},
 {index: 5, value: 'D'}]
```

I'm trying to turn that into an object like

```
{
  1: ['A', 'B'],
  2: ['C'],
  5: ['D']
}
```

Currently I'm just sorting the array, then running a convoluted for-loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) + [`.mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues) + [`.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map)

```js
var data = [{
  index: 1, value: 'A'
}, {
  index: 1, value: 'B'
}, {
  index: 2, value: 'C'
}, {
  index: 5, value: 'D'
}];

var result = _(data)
  .groupBy('index')
  .mapValues(function (el) {
    return _.map(el, 'value');
  })
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

also you can avoid several operation and can use only [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) like this

```js
var data = [{
  index: 1, value: 'A'
}, {
  index: 1, value: 'B'
}, {
  index: 2, value: 'C'
}, {
  index: 5, value: 'D'
}];

var result = data.reduce(function (prev, current) {
  if (typeof (prev[current.index]) === 'undefined') {
    prev[current.index] = [];
  }
  
  return prev[current.index].push(current.value) && prev;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Alexander's answer is probably a lot more clear than this, but I'm addicted to [partials](https://lodash.com/docs#partial) and allergic to anonymous functions, so here's a version with partials!

```
var data = [
    {index: 1, value: 'A'},
    {index: 1, value: 'B'},
    {index: 2, value: 'C'},
    {index: 5, value: 'D'}
];

// define a couple of resuable functions for these objects
var getValueProp = _.partial(_.get, _, 'value');
var mapToValueProp = _.partial(_.map, _, getValueProp);

// get the answer!
var result = _(data)
    .groupBy('index')
    .mapValues(mapToValueProp)
    .value();
```